# Не выодит категории на сайте из базы данных, в чем ошибка и что делать?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\localServer\OpenServer\domains\test.ua\includes\header.php on line 26

вот 26 строка:

while( $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories) )

а если весь код целиком то:

```
  <?php 
     $categories = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM (arlicles_categories)");
  ?>      <div class="header__bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
        <?php 
          while( $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories) )
          {
            ?>
            <li><a href="#"><?php $cat['title']; ?></a></li>
            <?php
          }
            ?>            </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, он не распознает переменную $categories, но я не понимаю почему.. она прописана в том же файле

Comment: Вам MySQL возвращает ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос в том, почему

Comment: Ну так Вы посмотрите, что это за ошибка. Очень может быть, что всё сразу станет понятно.

Comment: короче вопрос решен, и никуда смотреть не было нужды